# How to prevent private methods from being imported from a class in python?

Tags: python, class, methods, module, private

I am a beginner in Python and I am wondering how to prevent methods starting with an underscore (`_`) from being imported. I have a class called `Scrapper` which has four methods: `get`, `save`, `_is_data_available`, and `_collecting_data`. I only want the get and save methods to be imported by other modules.I tried adding **all** = ['get', 'save'] outside the class, but this did not work. How can I do this?

Comment: A method can't be *imported*, because it belongs to the namespace of a class, not a module. So `__all__` doesn't have an effect here.

Comment: The underscore is sufficient. If a third-party caller chooses to ignore that convention, you should never try to prevent it. (Of course, if your own code ignores it, that's a bug which needs fixing).